# The super type of the component X is unknown, some of its properties are not validated

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I is blackberry 10 developer. I use momentics IDE for develop blackberry 10 app

My project includes such 4 files:

1. (x.h)

   ```
   #ifndef X_H
   #define X_H
   #include "Y.h"

   class X: public Y {
       Q_OBJECT
   public:
       explicit X (QObject *parent = 0);
   /*...*/
   #endif
   ```
2. (y.h)

   ```
   #ifndef Y_H
   #define Y_H
   #include <QObject>
   #include <QtGui/QSortFilterProxyModel>

   class Y : public QSortFilterProxyModel {
     Q_OBJECT
   public:
     explicit Y (QObject *parent = 0);
   /*...*/
   #endif
   ```
3. (main.cpp)

   ```
   #include "x.h"
   #include "xModel.h"
   /*...*/
   qmlRegisterType<X>("com.lib", 0, 1, "X");
   qmlRegisterType<xModel>("com.lib", 0, 1, "xModel");

   /*...*/
   ```
4. (main.qml)

   ```
   import com.lib 0.1
   import bb.cascades 1.0


   Page {
   /*...*/
   attachedObjects: [
           X { /* INFOS: The super type of the component
                  X is unknown, some of its properties
                  are not validated.*/
               id: myclass
               sourceModel: xModel 
          },

          xModel {
               id: xMyModel
          }
   ]
   /*...*/
   }
   ```

But, when I build project in Momentics IDE I see that error, but if I build this code in QtCreator (import QtQuick instead of bb.cascades) then I don't see such error:

```
errors:  (asset:///main.qml:112:12: Cannot assign to non-existent property "sourceModel") 
bb::cascades::QmlDocument:createRootObject document is not loaded or has errors, can't create root
```

What should I do?

Comment: I'm actually surprised you don't get more errors, since since you apparently place the class definitions in *source* files, with `X` depending on `Y`. That won't work, unless you `#include` the source files (which you should not do). Class definitions used by different source files should be ut in *header* files, and you should only include those header files.

Comment: Or wait, that's what the question title references? However, you ask about a completely different error in the question body. Please make up your mind! Which error are you asking about?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course I use #include in those places where it is needed. I wanted to leave that part of the code, which seemed to me and affect my mistake.

Comment: The error lies in the fact that in qml somehow does not know about QSortFilterProxyModel, where and characterization sourceModel.

Comment: Then the title of your question is seemingly wrong. Please edit it to match the actual question, and if possible please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: And what is wrong in my question? The super type of the component X is unknown, some of its properties are not validated. This is the main problem. Ie the compiler can not find a super type of the object X. Sorry to put it is not entirely accurate. English is not my native language

Comment: Aleksandr it will admittedly take some time, but read through the link @JoachimPileborg offered you.

Comment: The error you say you have in the title, and the error you post in the question are ***not*** the same error. And I already provided you with a solution to the error *in the title* with my first comment. But really, please try to make more complete example code to show us (but still as minimal as possible). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I understand everything. Now I will correct my mistakes in question. Thank you

Comment: I add few new information

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Q_PROPERTY macro for each property you want your custom component to have, as others have commented already you should provide a little bit more code to really help you.

Anyway to add the sourceModel property you header file should look like this

```
#ifndef X_H
#define X_H
#include "Y.h"

class X: public Y {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(typeOfSourceModel sourceModelAccessor WRITE setSourceModel READ sourceModel NOTIFY sourceModelChanged)
public:
    explicit X (QObject *parent = 0);
/*...*/
#endif
```

where sourceModelAccessor, is an accessor for the sourceModel property, setSourceModel is a mutator and sourceModelChanged is a signal.

Take a look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html